# How to define a query parameter to be a list of specific values with Raml 1.0?

Tags: traits, query-string, raml

I've been looking around on how to define the following queryParameters in RAML 1.0

```
/api/route?attrs=attr1,attr2,attr3
```

Where attr1,attr2 and attr3 are specific values and each one must be present only once

to make it more clear if I have a return object like

```
{
  name: 'myName',
  lastName: 'myLastName',
  age: 20
}
```

The possible values in 'attrs' would be 'name','lastName' and 'age'.

i.e.

**These are valid:**

```
/api/route?attrs=name,lastName,age
/api/route?attrs=name,lastName
/api/route?attrs=name
```

**These are invalid:**

```
/api/route?attrs=name,lastName,name
/api/route?attrs=name,age,age
```

I appreciate your help and if anyone know how to accomplish this please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a regular expression pattern to validate the field.

https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#built-in-types

Comment: Thanks Rafael for your response, I missed this from the specification but I think this will solve my problem I will give it a try just need to write the right regex, I appreciate your help.